# How to make StringCases to understand the scientific form of numbers?

Tags: string-manipulation, number-representation

Consider the string

```
string="Tau_distribution_mass=547.0_theta=6.87982e-05.txt";
```

I would like to make a row

```
{distr,massvalue, thetavalue};
```

I write

```
StringCases[string, 
 mixing__ ~~ "_distribution_mass=" ~~ mass : NumberString ~~ 
   "_theta=" ~~ angle : NumberString ~~ ".txt" :> {mixing, 
   ToExpression[mass], ToExpression[angle]}]
```

but the problem is that NumberString does not recognize the scientific form of numbers, because of which the code returns empty. Could you please tell me what is an analog of NumberString in this example?

Comment: Rather than StringCases, I would use: `MapAt[Interpreter["Number"],StringSplit[string,{"_distribution_mass=","_theta=",".txt"}] ,{2;;3}]`

Answer (score 3):

This is a case for `RegularExpression`:

```
s = "Tau_distribution_mass=547.0_theta=6.87982e-05.txt";
regex = RegularExpression[
   "^([^_]+).*?(\\d+\\.+\\d*).*?(\\d+\\.+\\d*e+-+\\d*)"];

StringCases[s, regex -> "$1,$2,$3"]

{"Tau,547.0,6.87982e-05"}
```